# What would be a working modal code? Already tried some code

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I tried this code which worked on [www.homepage.com/en/index.php](http://www.homepage.com/en/index.php) but it did not work on [www.homepage.com/index.php](http://www.homepage.com/index.php) (without showing an error in the console). That is a very strange behavior!:

```
 <script src="../scripts/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>   
 <script src="../scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>   
 <script src="../scripts/jquery.reveal.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* set cookie for modal */
        var cname = "modal-home";
        var cvalue = "true";
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (20*60));// after 20min delete cookie modal-home
        var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
        $(document).ready(function() {
        /* if theres no cookie modal-home reveal modal */ 
        if ( !document.cookie.indexOf("modal-home=true") ) {
        $("#myModal").reveal();
        }
        });
    </script>
    <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal medium">
        <div class="inside text-center">
        ......
        </div>
        <a class="close-reveal-modal">&times;</a>
    </div>
```

Here you can see that there is jQuery two times included, and I'm not sure if that is really necessary. When I look for code for modal, I always find that with such "old"(?) jQuery code. Is that normal? Do I have to use both jQuery files? Or could I find code for a modal which would work also work with the jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js what also would reduce the JS code on the page.

Does somebody knows a code which would be better than the code I use in this example? Guess it's quite old, and may be you have experience with a better one?

Comment: You're not "using both jquery files" - you're only using the last one, which overwrites the previous ones.

Comment: It looks like you're using the reveal.js plugin for your modal - from what I can tell, it's quite an old plugin so needs an old version of jquery - but there could be any number of plugins with a basic name like "reveal.js" and you've not included your source.  You should consider using a newer plugin for your modal.  *could I find...* yes, go look for one, unless you're asking here for a recommendation? (which is off topic)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments! We have two websites, and this code was copied from the other website, which is much more bigger and not supported by me. I don't really know where this code comes from. In the meantime I've tried another code from bootstrap(!?), which works so far, but for me it seems pretty much code, a lot of unused code. So I would try to reduce this code a little bit.. and I also don't know if this code is also  an old version or needs also an old version of jquery. I would be really very happy if you could recommend here a better one! Thank you very much!